# GCM by Topics - messages are not being delivered in all clients

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

My app sends notification by topics through `GCM`. So far it has been installed in four different devices and an android emulator. All the messages reach the emulator, however, few of them reach the real devices. I don't have a real statistics (more than 4 clients) because it has not been released through play store. 
My emulator runs android 5.1 and the real devices have `Kitkat` and lower versions of android (from 4.1). I need to know how `GCM` delivers the message by topics, is it only one broadcast and that is it? and what happens with those devices which don't have the internet data enable by the time `GCM` broadcasts the message. once they have internet access can receive the messages? should it be so?

Comment: If your HTTP request doesnt contain the `time_to_live` parameter, its default is the maximum period of 4 weeks. Messages will be delivered to your devices, once they are turned on or have internet connection. You can check [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options?hl=en#ttl) for more details about the lifespan of a message.

Comment: Thanks for this info. I still wonder why the messages are not being delivered to some clients; it didn't pass more than few days from moment that the messages were sent by HTTP request. They were supposed to be delivered. I will add just in case the time_to_live option.